# Magento 2: setPageSize not working in block

Tags: magento2

> I am trying to get another product collection in the relate product
>   list block. However, I cannot set the page size for the new
>   collection. it always get all product of the system

**Follows are my code.
di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" type="AIS\Custom\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" /> 
</config>
```

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.age.indicator.block" template="AIS_Custom::ageindicatorblock.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock class="AIS\Custom\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                            name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                            template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**and the block php**

```
<?php
namespace AIS\Custom\Block\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class Related extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related {

    //override get item function
    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'required_options'
        )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Checkout')) {
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }
        $this->_itemCollection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        // try to get another new collection if related product is not enough
        if ($this->_itemCollection->getSize() < 5) {
            // create new collection
            $collection = $product->getCollection();
            $collection->addAttributeToSort(
                            'created_at',
                            'desc'
                        );
            // want to get 5 product
            $collection->getSelect()->limit(5);
            $collection->load();
            // it show all the product
            error_log($collection->getSize());
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

> I try to use same method to limit the collection and it is fine in
>   other custom file like controller, template but It is not work in this
>   file. May someone help me to solve or investigate this issue ?